# Functions of sagemaker service from js-sdk not recognize by AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, aws-sdk-js

I'm writing a lambda (in node.js 6.10) to update an endpoint SageMaker. To do so I have to create a new HyperParamterTuningJob (and then describe it).
I succeeded to call all functions of the service SageMaker from the sdk (like listModels, createTrainingJob, ...) (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SageMaker.html) except some of them.

All the functions that are related to HyperParameterTuningJob 
(createHyperParameterTuningJob, describeHyperParameterTuningJob, listHyperParameterTuningJobs and stopHyperParameterTuningJob) 
are not known in the sdk by the lambda.

I have attached the policy 'AmazonSageMakerFullAccess' to the role IAM used (where all these functions are allowed). So the error can't come from a problem of authorization.

I have already created a HyperParameterTuningJob (by the interface of AWS) called 'myTuningJob'.
I have an error everytime I use the function describeHyperParamterTuningJob.
Here is my lambda code :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sagemaker = new AWS.SageMaker({region: 'eu-west-1', apiVersion: '2017-07-24'});
var role = 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        HyperParameterTuningJobName: 'myTuningJob'
    };

    sagemaker.describeHyperParameterTuningJob(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log(data);
    });
};
```

When I try to test this code in AWS lambda, it returns this result in the console :

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: 6e79aaa4-9a18-11e8-8dcd-d58423b413c1 Version: $LATEST
2018-08-07T08:03:56.336Z    6e79aaa4-9a18-11e8-8dcd-d58423b413c1    TypeError: sagemaker.describeHyperParameterTuningJob is not a function
at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:10:15)
END RequestId: 6e79aaa4-9a18-11e8-8dcd-d58423b413c1
REPORT RequestId: 6e79aaa4-9a18-11e8-8dcd-d58423b413c1  Duration: 50.00 ms   
Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB  
RequestId: 6e79aaa4-9a18-11e8-8dcd-d58423b413c1 Process exited before completing request
```

When I call all other functions of the SageMaker service from the sdk, it runs correctly, whitout any error.

I don't find any explanation in the documentation of why these functions related to HyperParameterTuningJob are not recognized as functions in the sdk.

Does anyone have any idea of why it doesn't work ? Or any solutions to call theses functions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AWS Lambda, only the sdk that have a sable version are available.
The sdk of the SageMaker service is not stable yet, so functions related to HyperParameterTuningJob are not in the version of the sdk included in AWS Lambda.

To use theses functions, you need to install the latest version of the sdk on local on your machine (with npm install aws-sdk). 
Then zip the node_modules folder and your script (called index.js), then upload this zip folder into the AWS lambda.

Comment: ho do you find out if it is stable or not?